# Java8 LocalDate JPA2.2 persisting to postgresql's Date fails when LocalDate is null

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, java-8

I want to use `LocalDate` and `LocalDateTime` from Java8 DateTime API,
and having trouble persisting to postgresql `date` and `timestamp` when values are `null`.

Exception message:

```
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "some_date" is of type date but expression is of type character varying
hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
position: 61
Error Code: 0
Call: INSERT INTO TEST (ID, some_date, some_timestamp) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
bind => [0, null, null]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(mypackage.TestEntity@38c9e0d6)
```

my maven dependencies for postgresql driver and JPA2.2:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

My `test` table at postgresql10.1 (there is NO `not null` constraint):

```
create table test (id serial, some_date date, some_timestamp timestamp);
```

My `TestEntity` class:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Entity(name="test")
public class TestEntity {

    @Id
    private int id;

    @Column(name="some_date")
    private LocalDate someDate;

    @Column(name="some_timestamp")
    private LocalDateTime someTimestamp;

   //simple getters and setters here.
}
```

My `testMethod`:

```
public void testMethod() {
    TestEntity testEntity = new TestEntity();
    // IF I set both someDate and someTimestamp via setters,
    //I don't get any exceptions (table data will be added successfully)
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(testEntity);
    em.getTransaction().commit(); //this is where the exception occurs.
}
```

What am I missing? Is there any workaround for this?

**Edit:** 
After months, I realized that this is problem does not occur any more. May be because I switched the server implementation from Grizzly to Payara5.181. 
No custom converters required afterall (even if the value is `null`).

Comment: this hints at another problem. have you checked this: Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "some_date" is of type date but expression is of type character varying
hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bug in eclipselink https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=535431. When LocalDate value is null, there is no appropriate JDBC type mapping and by default it is set to VARCHAR and driver throws an exception.

As a workaround we created PatchedPostgreSQLPlatform with required mappings and set it as a value of eclipselink.target-database property.

```
public class PatchedPostgreSQLPlatform extends PostgreSQLPlatform {

    /**
     * Extended with java.time.* classes mappings.
     */
    @Override
    public int getJDBCType(Class javaType) {
        if (javaType == ClassConstants.TIME_LDATE) {
            return Types.DATE;
        } else if (javaType == ClassConstants.TIME_LTIME) {
            return Types.TIMESTAMP;
        } else if (javaType == ClassConstants.TIME_LDATETIME) {
            return Types.TIMESTAMP;
        } else if (javaType == ClassConstants.TIME_ODATETIME) {
            return Types.TIMESTAMP;
        } else if (javaType == ClassConstants.TIME_OTIME) {
            return Types.TIMESTAMP;
        } else {
            return super.getJDBCType(javaType);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a converter for the `LocalDate` attribute(JPA 2.1 and +) like this:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDate, Date> {

    @Override
    public Date convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDate locDate) {
        return (locDate == null ? null : Date.valueOf(locDate));
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate convertToEntityAttribute(Date sqlDate) {
        return (sqlDate == null ? null : sqlDate.toLocalDate());
    }
}
```

And use the converter in your `LocalDate` attribute:

```
@Entity(name="test")
public class TestEntity {

    @Id
    private int id;

    @Converter(converter=LocalDateAttributeConverter.class)
    @Column(name="some_date")
    private LocalDate someDate;

    ...

   //simple getters and setters here.
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I intended to use JPA2.2 feature (auto convert WITHOUT custom converters) and I wish it was implemented perfectly (with `null` case), but I gave up and am using your example of JPA2.1+. It's working OK.

Answer (score 0):

annotate someDate with `@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)` and someTimestamp with  `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)`... only sql types are saved with no hassle